# PHP exec python and get return array including chinese characters

Tags: php, python, exec

I need to execute an python script from my php script and get the return from the python file. 
This is my code:

PHP:

```
exec('python echo.py', $array, $ret_code);
echo $array;
```

Python:

```
def main():

    return ['TEST','本实用新型提供种新型行星齿轮减速器']


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(main())
```

It's working without the chinese characters, but as soon as I add them, I get  an empty array.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `python echo.py` from command line?

If your default Python is still v2, then installing Python3 and set it to default should help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already have Python3 (Python 3.6.3) installed and when I run it from command line I get some rectangles instead of the chinese characters, but I can copy and paste it to a text file and I'll get the chinese characters. It still doesn't work for my php file.

Comment: `echo shell_exec('python echo.py');` seems to work for me

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong but it doesn't work for me :/